# Efficient way of creating lots of winforms (about 50) for a vb.net application

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

I am working on a vb.net application with winforms and need to create lots of forms (about 50) for the user interface.

The layout of the forms schould be the same in terms of size (1920x1080), background colours, fonts, size of the controls etc.

Is there a way of creating winforms very efficient without creating every form with the designer?

I would like to define somekind of a template which the other forms are based on.

Should i create the forms with code without using the designer or is there a better way? Any ideas or best practices are welcome.

Comment: If you create a WinForm in the designer and use that as your template, you then instantiate each of your 50 forms `var newForm = new TemplateForm()` in a loop. Can you confirm how each form will be controlled? Will they need their own logic?

Comment: I think it's a bad practice to use MDI (with lots of forms in one application) when it's possible to do the same with TDI .

Comment: @gunner2607 They need to have their own logic and need to react the events of the controls.

Comment: @Fabjan I know the term MDI and SDI but never heard of TDI? Could you eloberate how you would organize the need for editing different data on different forms?

Comment: You should never fix the form size in the requirements like that.  Either Maximize the form to fill the whole screen at runtime, or set the form size to the screen working area.  Keep in mind that even on a 1920x1080 screen, *YOU* may not have all that space available.  If the task bar is set to not hide that will take up room - as will other AppBars/docks/launchers.  On Win 8 the Desktop may be running in a split screen container.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create the form with all the specification like size, background colours, fonts etc as your base form. This will act as your template.

Now when you add a new form it inherits from `Form` class by default. Instead of `Form` simply inherit your form from the `BaseForm`.

To have uniformity with the controls, you can create *User Controls* and use them instead to windows form controls.

[image]

Comment: I added a picture - you need to make sure the new form is an "inherited form"

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Class Form1

  Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    For i As Integer = 1 To 50
      Dim f As New Form
      f.Text = "Form " & i.ToString
      f.Width = 1920
      f.Height = 1080
      Dim b As New Button
      AddHandler b.Click, AddressOf CloseButton
      b.Text = "Close " & i.ToString
      b.Top = 100
      b.Left = 100
      b.Visible = True
      f.Controls.Add(b)
      f.Visible = True
    Next i
  End Sub

  Private Sub CloseButton(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim b As Button = DirectCast(sender, Button)
    b.FindForm.Close()
  End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Probably not what the OP is asking for - 50 *different* form types, editable in the designer, all of which share a common L&F.

Comment: @user2864740 thats what i want to do.

Comment: In that case use Yogi's method of an inherited form.